# March 2015 CU for sharepoint 2010 and 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, update

Do you recommend March 2015 CU installing for SharePoint 2010 and 2013?

[March 2015 CU for SharePoint 2010 has been released](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2015/03/10/march-2015-cu-for-sharepoint-2010-has-been-released.aspx)

[March 2015 CU for SharePoint 2013 has been released](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2015/03/10/march-2015-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-has-been-released.aspx)

Do you have any experience on that? did you see any bad impact after installing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I applied the CU for 2013 and so far no issue at my Test farm. A quick google tells me that their is one issue.

[March 2015 CU Task List Filter Issue SP2013](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9f885b83-888a-429a-828f-3aed13cddfdb/bug-found-in-march-2015-cu-affecting-quick-edit-task-list-views?forum=sharepointgeneral) But this issue fixed in the May 2015.

Also check this https://www.vioreliftode.com/index.php/sharepoint-incoming-e-mails-stuck-in-drop-folder/

As a Best practice, please apply the patch and perform the testing.

- test all the functionality your company is using.
- Best practice, copy the production data into Lower farm and perform the testing.

Comment: I have to install July 2014 Cumulative Update first?

Comment: What is ur farm patch level?

Comment: I don't have access to check that but I know we have SharePoint 2010 sp2 without any other update

Comment: for sp 2010 the base line is SP2 for March CU. For SharePoint 2013 base line is SP1 or March 2013 PU.

Comment: You are welcome, i hope now all your concern and issue resolved for the updates....also it is really appreciated if you up vote on the answer as well.

Comment: We have another sharepoint 2013 farm for internet facing, we do not have sp1 on that and now we are thinking to install security patches, do you suggest us to install sp1 or go with security patches? I don't know if sp1 includes security patches

Comment: I would adopt this path...SP1 followed by March CU 2015...then i am all set for now as well as for future updates